# Why is FreeQ so much faster for some specific variable names?

Tags: performance-tuning, implementation-details

It seems that performance of `FreeQ` depends on the names of symbols which appear in its arguments.

Here is an example of two large expressions which do not contain symbol `b`:

```
listac = RandomChoice[{a, c}, 1000000];
listat = RandomChoice[{a, t}, 1000000];
```

Applying `FreeQ` to these expressions results in very different timings:

```
RepeatedTiming[FreeQ[listac, b]]
RepeatedTiming[FreeQ[listat, b]]
```

> {5.*10^-7, True}
>
> {0.019, True}

Why can `FreeQ` instantly identify that `listac` doesn't contain `b`, but needs time to check `listat`?

Are there any recommendations on how to choose symbol names for best performance?

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with some sort of hash table data structure, but I'm not sure in what capacity.

Comment: This is bizarre. I tried this same thing with all the different (lower-case) letters of the alphabet in the second spot.  All of the `RepeatedTiming`s were really fast, *except* for `t`, `u`, and `v`!

Comment: See tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation. "Each expression contains a special form of hash code that is used both in pattern matching and evaluation." So in some cases what would be an O(n) test is instead O(1).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau's point can also be seen if we compare `RepeatedTiming[FreeQ[RandomChoice[{a, c}, 1000000], b]]` with `With[{listac = RandomChoice[{a, c}, 1000000]},RepeatedTiming[FreeQ[listac, b]]]` . Clearly, the standard $O(n)$ complexity reduces to $O(1)$ due to the way the *variable* `listac` is internally stored.

Comment: @Soner There is a difference in your timings, because `RandomChoice` takes time to create the expression.  In the first expression you include `RandomChoice` inside Timing, but in the second you don't. This is not related to `FreeQ` performance.

Comment: @Shadowray Of course, my bad! Thank you for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**TLDR:**

If you run into performance issues related to symbol names, rename your symbols such that `` System`Private`GetContentCode `` returns different values for each symbol you use.

**Details:**

I guess that the irregular performance of `FreeQ` is related to the indexing method used by Mathematica to speed-up pattern matching and evaluation. By indexing I mean creating an auxiliary data structure (index) which is stored alongside every expression and contains some information about the contents of the expression. Index is recalculated when expression is being constructed or updated.

Hypothetically, if one doesn't implement any indexing at all, the operations like `FreeQ` would always require to traverse the whole expression (what takes O(n) time). This will be far from optimal.

Another hypothetical extreme case would be to store a complete list of contained symbols alongside every expression. Such index will allow one to perform all `FreeQ` calls in O(1) time, but there will be serious practical disadvantages: such indexes will have variable size and will be hard to process and update.

Instead of keeping a complete list of symbols, one can store, for example, an array of bits, where the first bit indicates whether expression contains any symbols starting with letter "a", the second bit indicates if there are symbols starting with "b" and so on... Such bit array can be designed to have a fixed size (e.g. 32 or 64 bit) and it will be quick to process and update via standard bitwise operations.

Such indexing method is known as *bitmap indexing with binning* and is common in database management software. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmap_index)

In the example above, binning is performed by a function which maps arbitrary set of symbols (data structure with infinite cardinality) into a fixed-size bit array.

An inherent feature of bitmap indexes with binning is their irregular performance.
To explain this irregular performance let's consider a hypothetical `FreeQ` function which relies on the alphabetical bitmap index described above. If a large expression `expr` contains only symbols `a1` and `b1`, then  the corresponding index will indicate that this expression contains only symbols starting with "a" and with "b". If we now evaluate `FreeQ[expr, c1]`, our hypothetical `FreeQ` function can instantly (in O(1) time) return `True` because index of `expr` indicates that there are no symbols starting with "c". However if we evaluate `FreeQ[expr, a2]`, then our hypothetical `FreeQ` function will be unable to return a result based on the information in index. While the index shows that there are symbols starting with "a", it is not clear if specifically `a2` is a member of `expr`. Thus, our `FreeQ` function will have to traverse the expression and will take O(n) time.

In practice it may not be the best choice to use the first letter of the symbol name for indexing purposes.
For example, a user may decide to start all variable names with the same letter (e.g. `x1,x2,x3,...`). In this case the performance of functions which rely on indexing may be reduced.
Instead of the first letter of the symbol name, one can use, for example, the first letter (or first several bits) of some hash of the symbol name. In this case even symbols with very similar (but not identical) names will likely set different bits in the index and `FreeQ` will resort to traversing expressions more rarely. However there still will be collisions when hashed and binned names of two different symbols set the same bit in the index. I think that these type of collisions are responsible for the `FreeQ` irregular performance observed in the original question.

Based on developers' answers on this site, I assume that implementation of hashing/binning functions is proprietary information of WRI and they cannot share it. Luckily we don't need implementation details to resolve performance issues from the original question. We just need a way to check that binned indexes of symbols we use do not collide.

Mathematica has two undocumented functions with relevant names: `` System`Private`GetContentCode `` and `` System`Private`CouldContainQ ``. I guess that `GetContentCode` returns binned index for given expression and `CouldContainQ` performs O(1) check using this index. (Note that these functions have `HoldAllComplete` attribute and will not evaluate their arguments. That is why I use `Map` in the examples below.)

Here are the results of `GetContentCode` for several symbols (results are shown in base 2 for readability):

```
Map[BaseForm[System`Private`GetContentCode[#], 2] &, {a, b, c, d, t, u, v, List}]
```

> {$10000000000000000_2$, $1000000000000_2$, $1000000000_2$, $100_2$, $1000000000000_2$, $1000000000000_2$, $1000000000000_2$, $100000000000000000000000000000_2$}

Note that the ContentCodes for symbols named `b`, `t`, `u`, and `v` are exactly the same. These are the symbol names which cause O(n) performance of `FreeQ` when used together.

Next, let's consider the results of `GetContentCode` for expressions `listac` and `listat` defined in the original question:

```
Map[BaseForm[System`Private`GetContentCode[#], 2] &, {listac, listat}]
```

> {$100000000000010000001000000000_2$, $100000000000010001000000000000_2$}

If we interpret these ContentCodes as binned indexes we can instantly deduce which symbols may be contained in the corresponding expressions and which are definitely not there. For example, the ContentCode of symbol `d` is $100_2$ (i.e. third bit is set).
The ContentCodes of both `listac` and `listat` do not have third bit set, which means that these expressions definitely don't contain symbol `d`. The function `` System`Private`CouldContainQ `` gives the result consistent with this interpretation:

```
Map[System`Private`CouldContainQ[#, d] &, {listac, listat}]
```

> {False, False}

If we do a similar check for symbol `b` we get

```
Map[System`Private`CouldContainQ[#, b]&, {listac, listat}]
```

> {False, True}

which means that based on the information from index we can identify that `listac` can't contain symbol `b`. Expression `listat` could possibly contain `b` and we need to perform a full check to know for sure.

It is now not surprising that

```
System`Private`CouldContainQ[t, b]
```

returns `True`.

**Summary:**

Irregular performance of the `FreeQ` function in the original question is most likely related to some sort of binned bitmap indexing mechanism which Mathematica uses to speed-up evaluations. In majority of practical cases this mechanism allows `FreeQ` to reach O(1) performance instead of O(n). In some rare cases, collisions of binned indexes will reduce performance to to original O(n). If such collisions give noticeable increase of calculation time it may be helpful to rename used symbols such that their binned indexes do not collide. One can use `` System`Private`GetContentCode `` function to get the value of binned index for any given symbol name.

Comment: Interesting!  Is it possible to change the `GetContentCode` of a symbol, rather than having to choose a different symbol to avoid collisions?

Comment: @QuantumDot ContentCode of a symbol seems to be a fixed function of its name. I don't think that there is anything one can do besides renaming the symbol.